# perl script get stuck before creating Junit xml using TAP::Harness::JUnit

Tags: perl, junit, tap-harness

I really need your help.

I have a main script that uses TAP::Harness::JUnit for running my tests. Usually all tests runs and the xml created successfully.  but when I'm trying to run a certain test (called big_test) with a big output data, after the test finish running (takes about one hour), my main.t script get stuck and the xmlfile is never created.

in main.t I defined:

```
my $harness = TAP::Harness::JUnit->new({
            formatter_class => 'TAP::Formatter::JUnit',
        xmlfile     => "$new_xml_name",
            merge           => 1,
            normalize       => 1,
            color           => 1,
            timer       => 1,
            show_count  => 1,
            ignore_exit => 1,
            });
```

Does anyone have an advice?
Thanks